# SELF CLOSE a WebView window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, webview

Hello I am trying to close a WebView window automatically when the page code stop executing. I am adding this to the end of the page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      self.close();
</script>
```

And if I open the webview by clicking on a link in messenger the code works as expected - closes the webview as soon as it gets to it. However, if I open the same page from a link inside an already opened webview, then the code is not triggered and page is not closed.

In both cases I am using one and the same page and the code is added to the bottom of the page. The other code of the page is PHP and HTML

Any idea what is the reason?
The only think that might be is if the webview actually open the link in a new "tab" (not sure if tabs exist in webview) and as a result js cannot close it. This is just a thought.

Comment: try `window.close()`

Comment: Same behavior. Closes the if opened from messenger, but doesn't if the action is initiated inside the WebView